# Can I use port mapping in behavioral method and is using process comppulsory in behavioral modelling VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I have few doubt guys. Can I write a VHDL structural program with process? Can I write behavioral modeling without process? can i use port mapping in both behavioral and structural modeling? Is there any certain syntax rules for writing structural and behavioral in VHDL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's legal to mix any of those constructs (what's recommended is a different matter, and is somewhat subjective, so is probably off-topic here).

Behavioral modeling usually implies a process, and some (many?) designers avoid mixing processes with structural code (not me, in general), but there's nothing illegal about mixing them, and there's nothing "magical" about labeling an architecture with one or the other term.

Comment: +1 - It is just a label of describing the style. You can mix styles as you please (as long as you use valid syntax).

Answer (score 1):

Structural refers to a hierarchy of components. At some level all functional VHDL design models are abstract and behavioral, VHDL doesn't have native primitives.

An elaborated design model is comprised of a hierarchy, process statements, concurrent statements and their sequential equivalents (e.g. sequential procedure calls) are devolved into block statements (hierarchy) and/or equivalent processes.  Function calls are parts of expressions.

From IEEE Std 1076-2008 (the LRM):

> **Design entities and configurations**
>
> The *design entity* is the primary hardware abstraction in VHDL.  It
>   represents a portion of a hardware design that has well-defined inputs
>   and outputs and performs a well-defined function.   A design entity
>   may represent an entire system, a subsystem, a board, a chip, a
>   macro-cell, a logic gate, or any level of abstraction in between. A
>   *configuration* can be used to describe how design entities are put together to form a complete design.
>
> A design entity may be described in terms of a hierarchy of *blocks*,
>   each of which represents a portion of the whole design. The top-level
>   block in such a hierarchy is the design entity itself; such a block is
>   an *external* block that resides in a library and may be used as a
>   component of other designs. Nested blocks in the hierarchy are
>   *internal* blocks, defined by block statements (see 11.2).
>
> A design entity may also be described in terms of interconnected
>   components. Each component of a design entity may be bound to a
>   lower-level design entity in order to define the structure or behavior
>   of that component. Successive decomposition of a design entity into
>   components, and binding those components to other design entities that
>   may be decomposed in like manner, results in a hierarchy of design
>   entities representing a complete design. Such a collection of design
>   entities is called a design hierarchy. The bindings necessary to
>   identify a design hierarchy can be specified in a configuration of the
>   top-level entity in the hierarchy.

This is where you find the distinction between a design model's structure and behavior.

**Architecture bodies**

> An architecture body defines the body of a design entity. It specifies the relationships between the inputs and outputs of a design
>   entity and may be expressed in terms of structure, dataflow, or
>   behavior. Such specifications may be partial or complete.

Note you can extract the structure (netlist) without having a functional design model. The minimum specification is

```
architecture architecture_name of entity_name is
begin

end architecture;
```

and:

**Elaboration of a design hierarchy**

> The elaboration of a design hierarchy creates a collection of
>   processes interconnected by nets; this collection of processes and
>   nets can then be executed to simulate the behavior of the design.

From the glossary:

> **design hierarchy:** The complete representation of a design that results from the 
>   successive decomposition of a design entity into
>   subcomponents and binding of those components to other design entities
>   that may be decomposed in a similar manner.
>
> **model:** The result of the elaboration of a design hierarchy. The *model* can be executed
>   in order to simulate the design it represents.
>
> **execute:** (A) When first the design hierarchy of a model is elaborated, then its nets are initialized, and finally simulation
>   proceeds with repetitive execution of the simulation cycle, during
>   which processes are executed and nets are updated. (B) When a process
>   performs the actions specified by the algorithm described in its
>   statement part

A purely structural design model has no specified behavior, representing only a netlist. It doesn't do anything when simulated although when entities match target device primitives the netlist can be mapped directly.  Device vendors tend to provide design entities with architecture bodies supplying behavioral specifications for their target primitives.